# Choosing IP Address For Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet, connection, bindings

On my server I have 2 static IP addresses. I would like to set Firefox to use one IP address exclusively. Does anyone have any good ideas on achieving this?

Comment: This is not going to do you any favours. Almost no sites on the internet currently use IPv6. And even if they did, that's not really how this works - it will use IPv6 if and only if the target host address is an IPv6 address. Instead you should be looking for options to prefer `AAAA` DNS records over `A` records.

Comment: So what your saying is even if the site supports IPv6 its default is probably IPv4 and will always go to that one?

Comment: Am I correct that IP addresses only belong to systems, not software? With appropriate exception for virtualization, but you're still only getting an IP for a system, even if it is a virtual one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Firefox/Chrome to reach IPv6 websites?](http://superuser.com/questions/259188/how-can-i-get-firefox-chrome-to-reach-ipv6-websites)

Comment: You claim 'The IPv4 address is set as my main address'. Can you please explain that? Choosing addresses is usually done (by default) according to RFC6724 or RFC3484.

Comment: @SanderSteffann - After going back and looking it appears your right the IPv4 is not as said the "default". It appears to switch between the 2. Ill go back and rephrase

Comment: @DaveRandom - I think you've focused on the 4 vs 6 part of my question. Your link appears to go to someone trying to get a 4to6 tunnel up and running. I already have a IPv6 address so I don't need a tunnel... at least I don't think I do.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support explicitly binding it to a certain IP address. It uses the address selection mechanisms (for source address and destination address) provided by the operating system. Depending on your platform there are ways to change that, but you'll change it for the whole OS, not just Firefox.

Linux based systems use `/etc/gai.conf` for the destination address selection. Setting a fixed source address can be done in the routing table. Take a look at the `ip route add ... via ... src ...` command syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is available here.  This is what you needed http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.